# How to store data.id to php variable

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, laravel-blade

Please look at the code it is a wordpress theme template. Having issues to get post id, that's stored in data.id. It gets shown when we write `{{data.id}}`.

I need to get this value in a php variable.

I tried:

`$id =  $data->id;`

`$id =  $data['id'];`

But these don't work.

I need something so that: `$id = {{data.id}};`

Here is the orignal code in which the first line has `{{data.id}}`

```
<li id="listing-{{data.id}}" class="job_listing type-job_listing card-style--default style-grid {{data.styles.cardClasses}}">
```

```
<script id="tmpl-listingCard" type="text/template">

<?php
/**
 * Insert content before a listing.
 *
 * @since 2.0.0
 */
do_action( 'listify_listing_card_before' );
?>

<li id="listing-{{data.id}}" class="job_listing type-job_listing card-style--default style-grid {{data.styles.cardClasses}}">
    <div class="content-box">

        <?php
            /**
             * Insert content at the start of the listing.
             *
             * @since Unknown
             *
             * @hooked Listify_Astoundify_Favorites::render_js() - 10
             */
            do_action( 'listify_content_job_listing_before' );
        ?>

        <a href="{{data.permalink}}" class="job_listing-clickbox"<# if ( data.cardDisplay.target) { #> target="_blank"<# } #>></a>

        <header class="job_listing-entry-header listing-cover <# if ( data.featuredImage.url ) { #>has-image<# } #>" <# if ( data.featuredImage.url ) { #>style="background-image:url({{data.featuredImage.url}})"<# } #>>

            <?php
                /**
                 * Insert content before the listing header.
                 *
                 * @since Unknown
                 */
                do_action( 'listify_content_job_listing_header_before' );
            ?>

            <div class="job_listing-entry-header-wrapper cover-wrapper">

                <?php
                    /**
                     * Insert content at the start of the listing header.
                     *
                     * @since Unknown
                     */
                    do_action( 'listify_content_job_listing_header_start' );
                ?>

                <div class="job_listing-entry-meta">
                    <# if ( data.status.featured && 'badge' === data.styles.featuredStyle ) { #>
                        <div class="listing-featured-badge">{{data.i18n.featured}}</div>
                    <# } #>

                    <# if ( data.cardDisplay.title ) { #>
                        <h3 class="job_listing-title">{{{data.title}}}</h3>
                    <# } #>

                    <# if ( data.cardDisplay.address && data.location ) { #>
                        <div class="job_listing-location">{{{data.location.address}}}</div>
                    <# } #>

                    <# if ( data.cardDisplay.telephone && data.telephone ) { #>
                        <div class="job_listing-phone">{{data.telephone}}</div>
                    <# } #>

                    <?php
                        /**
                         * Insert content after other meta information.
                         *
                         * @since unknown
                         */
                        do_action( 'listify_content_job_listing_meta' );
                    ?>
                </div>

                <?php
                    /**
                     * Insert content at the end of the listing header.
                     *
                     * @since Unknown
                     */
                    do_action( 'listify_content_job_listing_header_end' );
                ?>

            </div>

            <?php
                /**
                 * Insert content after the listing header.
                 *
                 * @since Unknown
                 */
                do_action( 'listify_content_job_listing_header_after' );
            ?>
        </header>

        <# if ( data.cardDisplay.rating || data.cardDisplay.secondaryImage || data.cardDisplay.claimed ) { #>

        <footer class="job_listing-entry-footer">

            <?php
                /**
                 * Insert content at the start of the listing footer.
                 *
                 * @since Unknown
                 */
                do_action( 'listify_content_job_listing_footer' );
            ?>

            <# if ( data.cardDisplay.rating ) { #>
                <div class="listing-stars">
                    <# if ( data.reviews ) { #>
                        <# for ( var i = 1; i <= data.reviews.stars.full; i++ ) { #>
                            <span class="listing-star listing-star--full"></span>
                        <# } for ( var i = 1; i <= data.reviews.stars.half; i++ ) { #>
                            <span class="listing-star listing-star--half"></span>
                        <# } for ( var i = 1; i <= data.reviews.stars.empty; i++ ) { #>
                            <span class="listing-star listing-star--empty"></span>
                        <# } #>
                    <# } #>

                </div>
                <div class="heading_footer">

                 </div>

            <# } #>

            <# if ( data.cardDisplay.secondaryImage && data.secondaryImage.url ) { #>
                <div class="listing-entry-company-image listing-entry-company-image--card listing-entry-company-image--type-{{data.secondaryImage.type}} listing-entry-company-image--style-{{data.secondaryImage.style}}">
                    <# if ( data.secondaryImage.permalink ) { #><a href="{{data.secondaryImage.permalink}}"><# } #>
                        <img class="listing-entry-company-image__img listing-entry-company-image__img--type-logo listing-entry-company-image__img--style-{{data.secondaryImage.style}}" src="{{{data.secondaryImage.url}}}" alt="{{data.title}}" />
                    <# if ( data.secondaryImage.permalink ) { #></a><# } #>
                </div>
            <# } #>

            <# if ( data.cardDisplay.claimed && data.status.claimed ) { #>
                <span class="claimed-ribbon">
                    <span class="ion-checkmark-circled"></span>
                </span>
            <# } #>

        </footer>

        <# } #>

        <?php
            /**
             * Insert content at the end of the listing.
             *
             * @since Unknown
             */
            do_action( 'listify_content_job_listing_after' );
        ?>

    </div>
</li>

<?php
/**
 * Insert content after a listing.
 *
 * @since 2.0.0
 */
do_action( 'listify_listing_card_after' );
?>

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a javascript variable, its assign from php side, you can obtain it from php code, you should find where is javascript getting this variable data then you can find needed variable.

Comment: are you sure its javascript variable ?  they are used conditions also 

<# if ( data.status.featured && 'badge' === data.styles.featuredStyle ) { #>
                        <div class="listing-featured-badge">{{data.i18n.featured}}</div>
                    <# } #>

                    <# if ( data.cardDisplay.title ) { #>
                        <h3 class="job_listing-title">{{{data.title}}}</h3>
                    <# } #>

Comment: its not look like blade template. Are you sure it's a blade template?

Comment: its not blade but they used data like used in blade .

Comment: its wordplress template